# phoenix, upload image, controller

Tags: phoenix-framework, elixir

I began to study the phoenix, trying to make the attachment of images to the post and the load on Amazon s3. Made model, use this article http://learningelixir.joekain.com/elixir-arc-with-a-single-module/, made controller. When submitting a form I receive an error:

```
[info] POST /posts
[debug] Processing by Blog.PostController.create/2
  Parameters: %{"_csrf_token" => "DkM9WAdYfxQ/dS0qQjU/FBILIic+NgAAaqE2D6FDOMICwTlVGaxnUQ==", "_utf8" => "✓", "post" => %{"body" => "789", "image" => %Plug.Upload{content_type: "image/jpeg", filename: "basilico.jpg", path: "/tmp/plug-1473/multipart-108288-12435-6"}, "title" => "6363"}}
  Pipelines: [:browser]
[debug] QUERY OK db=0.0ms
begin []
[debug] QUERY OK db=0.3ms
INSERT INTO "posts" ("body","title","user_id","inserted_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5) RETURNING "id" ["789", "6363", 5, {{2016, 9, 5}, {20, 44, 48, 0}}, {{2016, 9, 5}, {20, 44, 48, 0}}]
[debug] QUERY OK db=123.3ms
commit []
[info] Sent 400 in 130ms
[debug] ** (Ecto.CastError) expected params to be a map, got: `%Plug.Upload{content_type: "image/jpeg", filename: "basilico.jpg", path: "/tmp/plug-1473/multipart-108288-12435-6"}`
    (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:343: Ecto.Changeset.do_cast/4
    (blog) web/models/image.ex:19: Blog.Image.changeset/2
    (blog) web/controllers/post_controller.ex:28: Blog.PostController.create/2
    (blog) web/controllers/post_controller.ex:1: Blog.PostController.action/2
    (blog) web/controllers/post_controller.ex:1: Blog.PostController.phoenix_controller_pipeline/2
    (blog) lib/blog/endpoint.ex:1: Blog.Endpoint.instrument/4
    (blog) lib/phoenix/router.ex:261: Blog.Router.dispatch/2
    (blog) web/router.ex:1: Blog.Router.do_call/2
    (blog) lib/blog/endpoint.ex:1: Blog.Endpoint.phoenix_pipeline/1
    (blog) lib/plug/debugger.ex:122: Blog.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
    (blog) lib/blog/endpoint.ex:1: Blog.Endpoint.call/2
    (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
    (cowboy) src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

my post.ex

```
defmodule Blog.Post do
  use Blog.Web, :model

  schema "posts" do
    field :title, :string
    field :body, :string
    has_one :image, Blog.Image
    belongs_to :user, Blog.User

    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:title, :body, :user_id])
    |> validate_required([:title, :body, :user_id])
  end
end
```

my image.ex:

```
defmodule Blog.Image do
  use Blog.Web, :model

  alias Blog.Uploaders

  schema "images" do
    field :name, :string
    field :upload, :any, virtual: true
    belongs_to :post, Blog.Post

    timestamps
  end

  @required_fields ~w(name)
  @optional_fields ~w()

  def changeset(model, params \\ %{}) do
    model
    |> cast(params, ~w(upload), [])
    |> put_name
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  end

  def put_name(changeset) do
    case changeset do
      %Ecto.Changeset{
        valid?: true,
        changes: %{upload: %Plug.Upload{content_type: "image/" <> _, filename: name}}
      } ->
        put_change(changeset, :name, name)
      _ ->
        changeset
    end
  end

  def store(%Plug.Upload{} = upload, image) do
    Uploaders.PostImage.store({upload, image})
  end

  def url(image, version) do
    Uploaders.PostImage.url({image.name, image}, version)
  end
end
```

my uploaders/post_image.ex:

```
defmodule Blog.Uploaders.PostImage do
  use Arc.Definition

  @acl :public_read
  @versions [:original, :show, :thumb]

  @heights %{
    show: 315,
    thumb: 30
  }

  def validate({file, _}) do
    ~w(.jpg .jpeg .gif .png) |> Enum.member?(Path.extname(file.file_name))
  end

  def transform(:thumb, _file) do
    {:convert, "-thumbnail x#{@heights[:thumb]} -gravity center -format jpg"}
  end
  def transform(:show, _file) do
    {:convert, "-strip -resize x#{@heights[:show]} -gravity center -format png"}
  end

  def storage_dir(version, {_, image}) do
    "uploads/posts/#{image.post_id}/images/#{image.id}/#{version}"
  end

  def filename(_version, {file, _}) do
    Path.rootname(file.file_name)
  end
end
```

and my post_controller.ex:

```
  def create(conn, %{"post" => post_params}) do
    user = Addict.Helper.current_user(conn)
    # user = Blog.Repo.get(Blog.User, user.id)
    changeset = Blog.Post.changeset(%Blog.Post{}, Map.put(post_params, "user_id", user.id))
    case Blog.Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, post} ->
        image_params = Blog.Image.changeset(%Blog.Image{}, post_params["image"])
        image = Ecto.Model.build_assoc(post, :image, image_params)
        Blog.Repo.insert!(image)
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Post created successfully.")
        |> redirect(to: post_path(conn, :show, post))
      {:error, changeset} ->
        render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

question: how to fix this error? and even if I should try to create a Image?

Comment: Do you mind posting the entire stack trace?

Comment: @KeithA of course, updated post

Comment: Ok I believe I may have found your issue. In the `create` function in `post_controller.ex` you're passing in a `Plug.Upload` struct into the second parameter to the `Blog.Image.changeset` function.

Basically, `Blog.Image.changeset(%Blog.Image{}, post_params["image"])` should be `Blog.Image.changeset(%Blog.Image{}, a_map)` where `a_map` should be a map instead of a `Plug.Upload` struct

Comment: Thank you @KeithA! I replaced the code of action create (I hope I have understood you correctly) on a `upload_params = %{content_type: post_params["image"].content_type, filename: post_params["image"].filename, path: post_params["image"].path}; 
image_params = Blog.Image.changeset(%Blog.Image{}, upload_params); 
image = Ecto.Model.build_assoc(post, :image, image_params)`, but now I get a different error: `    ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Ecto.Model.build_assoc/3 is undefined or private. Did you mean one of:
      * build/2
      * build/3 `

Comment: Sory, I found a mistake `image = Ecto.build_assoc(post, :image, image_params)`, but the record is inserted in the end without name: `INSERT INTO "images" ("post_id","inserted_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3) RETURNING "id" [18, {{2016, 9, 5}, {21, 42, 46, 0}}, {{2016, 9, 5}, {21, 42, 46, 0}}]`

Comment: I think you have to edit the `put_name` function in `image.ex`. Change this `%Ecto.Changeset{
        valid?: true,
        changes: %{upload: %Plug.Upload{content_type: "image/" <> _, filename: name}}
      }` to this `%Ecto.Changeset{
        valid?: true,
        changes: %{upload: %{content_type: "image/" <> _, filename: name}}
      }`. The change you made previously is being sent to this function as a map but the function is still expecting a `Plug.Upload` struct.

Comment: Unfortunately, name also not recorded: `%Ecto.Changeset{ valid?: true,
changes: %{upload: %{content_type: "image/" <> _, filename: name}} }` trace: `INSERT INTO "images" ("post_id","inserted_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3) RETURNING "id" [19, {{2016, 9, 6}, {7, 29, 39, 0}}, {{2016, 9, 6}, {7, 29, 39, 0}}]`

Answer (score 0):

In your `Blog.Image`:

- the `schema` definition should have the field `upload` of type `Blog.Uploaders.PostImage.Type`:

`schema "images" do
 field :upload, Blog.Uploaders.PostImage.Type
 ...
end`

- changeset should call `cast_attachments` for the `upload`:

`def changeset(model, params \\ %{}) do
    model
    # NOTE: don't include upload here, or it will be processed twice
    |> cast(params, ~w(name), [])
    |> put_name
    |> cast_attachments(params, [:upload])
end`

Hope this helps.